# Piano student doing AMEB Grade 5 Leisure series : Axel F by Harold Faltemeyer

Tags: piano, tempo

(Tempo) Crotchet = ca. 88 meaning

I found above tempo in an exam piece but find the speed quite slow. 
Wondering is there a difference between ca 88 or c88 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C means circa - 'about'. Sort of give or take 10% either way. However, the original tempo is somewhere close to 116bpm, quite a lot quicker! I'd be on the phone to AMEB (wherever in the world it is) and query them about it. Often, exam boards publish recordings of their pieces, so it could be possible to check that way too. Found one, it's about 114bpm!